# How do you check if a integer is in an array?

Tags: c#

this is an example of the code I created

```
int[] Numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

What I would like to do is is a small script that can check if a number is in the array and return a boolean for example 3 would return true and 13 would return false otherwise the only way i can think of is this

```
if ((UserInput == Numbers[0]) || (UserInput == Numbers[1]) || (UserInput == Numbers[2]) || (UserInput == Numbers[3]))
```

Comment: Number.Contains(UserInput). Writing code involves also searching and learning

Comment: _"the only way i can think of"_ You need to go and learn about loop constructs at a minimum, but there are shorthand methods available for this too.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one can't find a duplicate.

Comment: If you're too lazy to declare Numbers...

if ({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}.Contains(UserInput)) {  // do Something }

Answer (score 9):

You can use the LINQ extension method [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb352880(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
bool containsNumber = Numbers.Contains(UserInput);
```

If `UserInput` is a `string`, you should parse it first:

```
int i;
if (int.TryParse(UserInput, out i)) // parse the string, and put it in i
{
    bool containsNumber = Numbers.Contains(i);
}
else
{
    // report to user the input is wrong
}
```

If you want to do the `Contains` check manually, you can use this:

```
bool containsNumber = false;

foreach (int n in Numbers) // go over every number in the list
{
    if (n == UserInput) // check if it matches
    {
        containsNumber = true;
        break; // no need to check any further
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bool containsNumber = Numbers.Contains(13);
```